# Deactivating RF modulator circuit, should I cut off the supply voltage as well?

Tags: voltage, grounding

I asked a [qeustion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559817/deactivating-rf-modulator-circuit-in-an-amiga-1200-minimum-required-parts-to-re) about this mod I'm doing to my Amiga 1200, but unfortunately I asked two questions at once, and only one question got answered. This is about removing an RF modulator from the computer's PCB and getting rid of electrolytic caps that are associated with the RF circuity and making sure that the leftovers aren't causing any trouble.

Here's the part of the schematic that shows the situation as is:

[image: RF modulator circuit of Amiga 1200]

**R** = replaced electrolytic capacitor
**X** = removed part that is not going to be replaced
**?** = should I remove these?

Removing R237 and E232R would cut off the IC (it's a Sony CXA 1145M) mono audio out and video power supply line repectively from going to ground. Mono audio **input** has already been disconnected from the IC (AUDIO_IN pin 8 not in picture) because there was an electrolytic cap before the input, but maybe the video encoder will now amplify noise and still give an output voltage at AUDIO_OUT (9)?

I'm a beginner when it comes to electronics and looking at this from my point of insufficient knowledge what I'm worried about is that without the RF modulator consuming power, the remaining resistors are overheating or something.

I doubt I will ever revive the RF output part of this computer ever again, so to be on the safe side I can live with removing a few SMD parts. What I mostly care about is that the remaining components do not interfere with the rest of the computer, consume unnecessary power or might even overheat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to remove E232 or R237. They will not overheat, in fact they will dissipate less power with X2 removed.  If there is no complete circuit for the current to flow then the resistors will not dissipate any power.  R237 will still dissipate some due to R238 still being in the circuit.

You can verify that the resistor is not dissipating any power (or very little) by measuring across it with a voltmeter.  If it says 0V, then there is no power dissipation in it.  If it has some voltage, the equation to calculate power \$(P)\$ in a resistor \$(R)\$is:
$$ P=\frac{V^2}{R}$$
Where \$V\$ is the voltage measured across the resistor.